# osTicket API: create a new ticket in python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, osticket

I'm trying to use `python` to create a new ticket, but I can't make [`osticket`](http://osticket.com/) accept my API key.

Here is my code:

```
def post_ticket(json):
  headers = {'API-Key': 'mykey'}
  response = requests.post("http://mydomani.com/api/tickets.json", data=create_json_ticket(json), headers=headers)
  for r in response:
    print(r)
```

I'm getting error `'Valid API key required'`.
If I use the `PHP` script given as example (using same url, key and JSON data) it works fine.

Comment: Could you provide the complete working code? I have the same issue (`Valid API key required`), but have double checked the header and also the API key works in Postman.

Comment: Sorry, but I no longer have access to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header key should be `"X-API-Key"` and not `"API-Key"`.

From [`osTicket API`](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.7/blob/develop/setup/doc/api.md) page:

> *HTTP Access*
>
> Access to the HTTP API is restricted to valid API keys. An **X-API-Key**
>   HTTP header must be sent to indicate which API key is to be used with
>   the request.
>   The API key must match the remote IP of the connected
>   HTTP client. The remote IP is checked as usual. If the osTicket server
>   is sitting behind a reverse proxy, the original IP of the client will
>   be retrieved from the X-Forwarded-For header, if provided by your
>   proxy.
>
> *Example:*
>
> `X-API-Key: BA00B76BAA30F62E1940B46CC1C3C73C`
>
> *Command line Example with Curl:*
>
> `curl -d "{}" -H "X-API-Key: BA00B76BAA30F62E1940B46CC1C3C73C" https://support.you.tld/api/tickets.json`

Comment: ye, as you said, i'm such an idiot, i ve read those pages hundred times, but never noticed that X- ..

Comment: @MicheleIetri I'm happy to help ;-) and I would never say you are an idiot!